# Liquibase Bean creation exception

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, liquibase

I'm getting error with Liquibase. I'm using spring.liquibase.change-log in my yaml file.

The error comes like this **"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yml"**

Please suggest any solution

Comment: does this file `/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yml` exist on your classpath? if yes, whats the content of this file?

Comment: Yes that exist. The file consists,
"databaseChangeLog:
        - include:
                  file: db/changelog/db.insert-master-1.0.xml"

Comment: @Bekan can you include your yml code & basic project structure ?

Comment: project structure: application->src->main->resources->db->changelog(contains db-insert-master.xml and changelog-master.yaml)

databaseChangeLog:
                   - include:
                                 file: db/changelog/db.insert-master-1.0.xml